# Send umlauts in JSON using HTTPRequest

Tags: c#, json, http

I am trying to send a JSON string using POST to a web service running on Azure. The program is an app created with Xamarin Forms.
The JSON communication with the server basically works but I have problems with umlauts.

I have a class "Test"

```
public class Test
{
    public string ä { get; set; }            
}
```

which I try to serialize into a string. I use JsonConvert for this:

```
string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

This results in {"ä":"ä"}.

When I send this string I get a 400 Bad Request error message.

Interestingly, sending this string using the Firefox Plugin "Open HttpRequester" works perfectly.

Changing the first umlaut into "ae" ({"ae":"ä"}) works though.

Here the C# code I use for sending the string:

```
private void Send()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(serverPath);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(UploadWithRequestStream), request);
}

private void UploadWithRequestStream(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    Test test = new Test();
    test.ä = "ä";
    string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test); // {"ä":"ä"}

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    Stream uploadStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    uploadStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
    uploadStream.Flush();
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
}

private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    // 404 Bad Request
}
```

Comment: try `request.ContentType = "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Thank but this didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've got a problem in this line:

```
uploadStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
```

You upload bytes from byteArray and count them as chars. But a single char (specifically, umlaut) could map to two bytes. In your example byteArray.Length = 11, and postData.Length = 9. That's why you send a shortened version of postData and it couldn't be processed by the server.

Replace the mentioned string with the string below and everything is fine:

```
uploadStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```